# PHP login doesn't work

Tags: php, session

I have a login screen but there seems to be a problem
When i click on Login the error:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS appears.

I can't figure out what causes this, does anyone have an idea?

login.php:

```
<?php
    include('db/login.php'); // Include Login Script
    if ((isset($_SESSION['email']) != '')) 
    {
    header('Location: modal.php');
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Log In | DKTP</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" type="text/css">
        </head>

    <body>

      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="fleft">

        </div>

     <center>

    <div id="login-form">
        <form method="post">
            <table align="left" width="32%">

        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/logo.png" align="center"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Aanmelden met DTKP account</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="iemand@dktp.nl" required=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*******" required=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login "></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <div class="error"><?php echo $error;?></div>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

     </center>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

db/login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db/dbconnect.php"); //Establishing connection with our database

$error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if(empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
{
$error = "Both fields are required.";
}else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect from MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
$password = md5($password);

//Check username and password from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
//Otherwise echo error.

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $login_user; // Initializing Session
header("location: modal.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}else
{
$error = "Incorrect username or password.";
}

}
}

?>
```

db/dbconnect.php:

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Iamthebest1009');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'dktp');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

?>
```

modal.php:

```
<?php
include("db/check.php"); 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modal.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
<body>

<h1 class="hello">Hello, <em><?php echo $login_user;?>!</em></h1>
<br><br><br>
<a href="logout.php" style="font-size:18px">Logout?</a>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="btn">Thema</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Kies thema</h2>
    </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="tablenorm.php"><button id="btn2">Normen</button></a>
        <a href="tableorden.php"><button id="btn2">Ordenen</button></a>
        <a href="tableclust.php"><button id="btn2">Clusteren</button></a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

<script src="js/modal.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

db/check.php

```
<?php
include('db/dbconnect.php');
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['email'];

$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user=$row['email'];

if(!isset($user_check))
{
header("Location: modal.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: `if ((isset($_SESSION['email']) != ''))` is a false positive. It needs to be broken up into two separate conditions. One to check if it is set and the other to check if it is not empty.

Comment: You should not go live with this code, using md5 since it's not safe. Are you taking this online?

Comment: redirect loop maybe?

Comment: could even be a mod rewrite somewhere in `.htaccess`, who knows. I think the OP's gone AWOL.

Comment: I suspect this `if(!isset($user_check))
{
header("Location: modal.php");
}` You are on `modal.php` already and might happen that your session is not set and u keep on redirected to the same page all the time and that page also redirects u again to it self

Answer (score -2):

in `login.php`:

Change

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['email']) != ''))
```

To:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['email']))
```

Regarding the "why" this should solve the problem:

In php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

`isset` : `Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise`.

Comment: actually, that should have been set into two separate conditions, given if they want to check for both.